# HTML: Prevent hide of options in select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

Is it possible not to hide options when I select item in 'select'? I need to append more options to 'select' when user click on 'op2' item, but without closing option list.

```
<select>
<option>op1</option>
<option>op2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: We need to see your code + HTML.

Answer (score 1):

This is an HTML option : `size="x"`

```
<select id="test" size="5">
    <option>op1</option>
    <option>op2</option>
    <option>op3</option>
    <option>op4</option>
    <option>op5</option>
    <option>op6</option>
</select>
```

You can then set the said size using jQuery :

```
$("select#test").attr("size",$("select#test > option").length);
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/crQHv/4/)

Answer (score 0):

`<select multiple>` might be what you want.